# Python code run through VBA - want to output log to text file

Tags: python, vba

I am trying to run the below VBA code that runs a python script and copies the log output to a text file.

The script runs fine but the text files are not created. Please help.

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "C:\Users\mmodi1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe Hello_World.py 1>code_log.txt 2>code_error.txt"
```

I want to save the log to code_log.txt and errors to code_error.txt. The above code runs the python script but does not create the text files.

Comment: What about using `>code_log.txt` instead of `1>code_log.txt` ?

Comment: Nope.. it doesn't work

Comment: What if you manually type `C:\Users\mmodi1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe Hello_World.py 1>code_log.txt 2>code_error.txt` in cmd, exactly as it is ?

Comment: I tried that sir.. it works perfectly fine in cmd.. 2 files are created.. but somehow through VBA only the code runs, the files do not get created

Comment: The files might have been created but somewhere you don't expect them. before `wsh.Run` try using `wsh.CurrentDirectory = the path you wish the logs are created` or specify full path for logs files